# Frequent design issue in Symfony, model calculation logic in entity

Tags: entity-framework, doctrine, symfony

I frequently experience a design issue in Symfony, i am not sure if i am solving it optimally.

Let me give an example:

```
Entity Merchant Account
property $dailyProcessingLimitation // Int
property $orders // ArrayCollection
```

An entity named Merchant account has a daily processing limitation, set to X euro's.

I want to check if a specific merchant account has reached its processing limitation, to do this i do the following:

I fetch all orders for today, and convert them all to a single currency, to do this, i need some stuff like a currency converter, so i cannot do this inside of the entity, since i should not be injecting the container into the entity.

So i have to create a "MerchantAccountManager", and do something like this:

```
$merchantAccountManager = $this->container->get('merchant_account_manager');
$totalForAccount = $this->getTotalProcessedForMerchantAccount($merchantAccount);
```

Is there any proper way to be able to call this directly on the entity, rather then adding  this which feels like ugly coding.

Reason as to why i feel it feels like bad design, is that the other developer has to know that the service exists, rather then being able to inspect the entity methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if some MerchantAccount is reached limitation? It can't receive new orders? I this case, just place into your MerchantAccount methods and use it.

```
public function addOrder(Order $newOrder)
{
    if (($order->getAmount() + $this->getOrdersAmount()) <= $this->dailyProcessingLimitation) {
        throw new Exception('The limit has been reached');
    } else {
        $this->orders->add($order);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function getOrdersAmount()
{
    $result = 0;
    foreach ($this->orders as $order) {
        $result += $order->getAmount();
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply could use the entity to get all orders and calculate based on certain conditions whether the daily processing limit is breached:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity

class MerchantAccount {
...
public function getTotalForAccount()
{
    $sum = 0;

    foreach($this->getMerchant()->getOrders() as $order)
    {
        if(//WHATEVER CONDITIONS YOU NEED) {
            $sum += $order->getAmount();
        }
    }

    return $sum;
}
...
```

Have a look at: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/aggregate-fields.html

Or you could just write DQL to aggregate using a query directly!